# What percentage of failed requests is "normal"

Tags: testing, code-quality

So I just launched my first "real" site that actually has a decent amount of interactions and whatnot. It's an ASP.net site with a SQL backend.

We've served 130k requests in the last 12 hours but 930 failed. Is this normal, bad, or "I should fire myself as a programmer" bad. While ideally this number would be 0, what's an acceptable percentage of failed requests?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I think it's a pretty fair novice question for programmers to ask themselves. If I had asked on StackOverflow, sure downvote it, but there's a reason I asked here and while clearly I wasn't asking myself the right question originally, I think it's still a very valid question.

Comment: I didn't vote but those who did likely feel that question [lacks research effort](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) and is a bit [broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490). Also see [ask]

Comment: Thanks for that @gnat, I actually have over 1000 rep on the regular stackoverflow but those are fair concerns, thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a "failed request"? Does it mean that the site didn't behave as it should, or that an error was returned? If an error was returned, was it for a legitimate action or due to an error (or malicious intent) on the user's side?

Comment: Please list the top few reasons of failure of requests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Percentage of requests is not the right way to look at it as it depends entirely what the failure is.  If you have one failure that exposes customer credit card information out of a million requests, that is utterly unacceptable.  On the other hand, 10% of calls resulting in a failure to show the correctly updated time is probably ok.

To determine if your situation is acceptable, you have to dig down, classify the errors, and decide for yourself.  The things to consider:

- Does the failure destroy data?
- Does the failure expose data?
- Does the failure prevent the user from doing something that earns you money?
- Does the failure prevent the user from doing what they want to do?
- Is it obvious to the user how to recover from the error?
- Is the error likely to give customers a negative opinion of your site?

Then for each discrete type of error, try to determine if the pain caused by the error is worth the cost of fixing the error.  If it is not worth the cost, then it is "acceptable", otherwise, it is not.  But it's a subjective question.

What I find works well is to simply measure these errors, prioritize them with questions like the above, and then work on fixing from the top, down until I reach cases that are either too hard to fix to be worth addressing.